# most efficient way to loop through DataFrames with many rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code to loop through 2 DataFrames, but it takes too long to complete the process. I wanted to know if there is a faster way to do this without using for, files have too many columns

The code brings me 2 columns if the `ID(SAP Order ID)` is the same in both files

```
df = pd.read_excel('1.xlsx',
                      sheet_name = '1',
                      header = 0,
                      )

df2 = pd.read_excel('2.xlsx',
                      sheet_name = '2',
                      header = 0,
                      )

for i in df['SAP Order ID']:
    for e in df2['SAP Order ID']:
        if i == e:
            df['FECHA DE DESPACHO'] = df2['FECHA DE DESPACHO']
            df['N° Guía Despacho  / Factura'] = df2['NUMERO DE GUIA/FACTURA']
```

Thanks!

Comment: @BigBen I think its excel files opened in `pandas`

Comment: @BigBen yes, srry, those are .xlsx files

Comment: @JorgeAliguery add the code where you open the files and probably replace the "excel files" in the headline by "dataframes".

Comment: there is @user_na

Comment: @BigBen I understand, srry

Comment: This is of O(np) complexity (n and p being the sizes of the 2 dfs); one simple way to convert it to O(n+p) would be to parse through the first, making a dictionary `SAP Order ID: other row info`, then parse through the 2nd and use the dict.

Comment: When working with dataframes, like any relational data in a set based language, it's best to avoid loops. Instead consider a merge: `df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='SAP Order ID', how='Left')` That will make a third dataframe that contains all rows from `df1` and all columns from `df2` where the `SAP Order ID` matches. Then you can keep whichever columns you like. It should be MUCH faster than your double for loop.

Comment: Agreed on what @JNevill said about merge. if you can't get that to work, post some example data so people can try to give you an exact response.